# How below macro is working in c programming language?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor, format-specifiers, using-directives

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define puts "%s C preprocessor"
int main()
{
    printf(puts, puts);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```txt
%s C preprocessor C preprocessor
```

[See also...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJzVc.png)

Can anyone explain me the logic behind this output?

I tried to solve it,but I didn't get the proper explanation through my friends. If anyone can explain me ,it'll be very helpful.

Comment: Post code as text here instead of an external link of an image.  Tell us what you have done so far to solve your problem.  Macros are covered in any textbook on c.   Don't shout (use all upper case).

Comment: What is your closest explanation you can come up with? What did you find out how the macro is replaced by preprocessor? Which part is missing then to get the output?

Comment: @AllanWind you don't shout

Comment: @Gerhardh , no part is missing. closest explanation would be % s is taking next argument as a string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro let to (code after linker):

```
int main
{
    printf("%s C preprocessor", "%s C preprocessor");
    return 0;
}
```

`printf` works like:

[image]

The output is then

```
%s C preprocessor C preprocessor
```

Comment: what's the reason behind this output?

Comment: A, reason for this outpul?  why is%s got printed?

Comment: Well, at first the linker changes the code because of the macros. Then printf has 2 identical strings. The first string is taken as formatstring, the second one as a simple string. Then printf replaces the "%s" in the formatstring by the second argument. There the "%s" will not be replaced, because its not in the formatstring.

Comment: Added an image of how the substitution in printf works

Comment: if i need to go through this topic in detail about formatstring, which topic would you suggest me to study?

Comment: The image in in the answer. I added it there. - And to get information about printf, type it in your favorite search engine.

Comment: thankyou andy, it's so much clear with the help of an image.

Comment: "Ein Bild sagt mehr als tausend Worte" :-) ... One Look Is Worth a Thousand Words

Comment: yes, absolutely

Comment: one more thing, in this printf is working from right to left?

Comment: And now, be so kind an rewrite your question with lowercase letters. To write all uppercase classified as rude!

Comment: `printf ( FORMAT, LIST )` -> `printf ( FORMAT, x, y, z)` -> All "%" in "FORMAT" will be replaced by the elements of the list. You have to look at a tutorial!!!

Comment: i didn't know that, uppercase is considered as rude. thankyou for telling me.